# What are some ways to display 3 dimensional data in a table?

Tags: info-visualisation, data-analysis

I have some data that has 2 dimensions that I currently display the values of in a table. The dimensions are Gender & Age. For example "there are 12 thirty year old Males".

Now I need to add a 3rd dimension to this data visualization - Religion. Ideally it would help the user:

1. See what intersections are represented (eg. there are 8 thirty year old, Christian Males)
2. See what intersections are not represented (eg there are no twenty five year old Buddhist Females)

What are some ways to present this data in a meaningful way that helps the user achieve the two objectives outlined above?

Answer (score 4):

This will give you a 0-10 age of a Male or Female with the Christian religion.

0-10 can be defined fix number, up to you to alter the visuals.

[image]

Comment: Not going to work so well if you open your gender options up, but good for a binary solution

Comment: @toni maybe the boxes could be pie charts instead for the genders. Could work better.

Answer (score 3):

it is my idea with table grid pattern. the idea is same like above answer but pattern and visualisation is different. [image]

Comment: All value boxes have the same size... Hard to read the values at a glance. Also confusing: "Below 80" includes all the other ages (0-80) or is it just the range between 70-80?

Comment: Good concept though. I like the idea.

Comment: Actually those values are not represent age in the boxes. those are no. of people belonging to age group.  (Ex:Below 80 there are 60 years old Males 72 year old Females belongs to Christian Religion)  @Luciano

Answer (score 2):

One way to display a 3rd dimension in a table would be to use [hierarchy](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for, 
Category and the value been a two dimension, the Series is the third value.

**Example**
Christian male would be your third value.

[image]

Image source:https://www.smartdraw.com/bar-graph/

Comment: No, that's still 2 dimensions...Category and Series. Value isn't a dimension.

Comment: Ok, I created another visual, and make it a new answer.